# How to collect functions results into one array and return this array?

Tags: php, mysql

My php function looks like that

```
function generateTour ($lang, $db)
{
    echo '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">';
    $title='title_'.$lang;
    $txt='txt_'.$lang;
    $result = $db->query("SELECT id, $title, $txt FROM 1_table");
    $count= $result->num_rows;
    $i=1;
    while($row=$result->fetch_object())
    {
    if($i%3==0) echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td width="33%">
    <div class="tour_item" style="background-image:url(core/content/img/pages/1/slide/'.$row->id.'.png)">
    <div class="tour_item_title"><a href="?id='.$row->id.'">';
    echo '</a></div><div class="tour_item_text"><a href="?id='.$row->id.'"></div>
    </div>';
    if($i==$count-1) echo '</td></tr>'; 
    else if($i%3==0) echo '</td></tr><tr>'; 
    $i++;
}
    echo '</table>';
}
```

As you see it echoes result line by line.  Not all at once. I want to collect all variables to one array and return this array. Is it possible? how to do it?

Please don't post your ideas about security holes .. etc. I'm filtering `$title, $txt` varibales against sql injections. (i have array for of possible field names. My filter function checks theese variables' values every time. )

Comment: +1 For whitelisting those fieldnames, you may want to enclose them in bacticks ` , just in case.

Comment: It's your advise, bro. thx very much

Comment: Which variables do you want to collect? You wrote "all" which is not very concrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetchObject()) {
   $data[] = $row;
}
```

Is the absolutely most basic method of cacheing a result set in an array. You'd just modify this to store your generated html instead.

Comment: I want to collect whole funtion's result into one array (including all echoes)

Comment: Then don't do echoes. assign to a variable and do repeated string concatentation. But why an array then? If you're doing one single big string, then stuffing that string into an array is pointless. It's like putting a box in a box.

Comment: take a look at scoutman's solution. Is there anyway to reduce this solution's code?

Comment: No, not really. Generating HTML is always going to imply that your code is going to be bigger than the html itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function generateTour ($lang, $db)
{
    $output = '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">';
    $title='title_'.$lang;
    $txt='txt_'.$lang;
    $result = $db->query("SELECT id, $title, $txt FROM 1_table");
    $count= $result->num_rows;
    $i=1;

    while($row=$result->fetch_object())
    {
        if($i%3==0)
        {
            $output .= '<tr>';
        }

        $output .= '<td width="33%">
        <div class="tour_item" style="background-image:url(core/content/img/pages/1/slide/'.$row->id.'.png)">
        <div class="tour_item_title"><a href="?id='.$row->id.'">
        </a></div><div class="tour_item_text"><a href="?id='.$row->id.'"></div>
        </div>';

        if($i==$count-1)
        {
            $output .= '</td></tr>';
        }
        else if($i%3==0)
        {
            $output .= '</td></tr><tr>';
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $output .= '</table>';

    return $output;
}
```

**Edit:**
Now it's easier to read the code. This solution put all content in one variable. You don't need a array.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the data in the db using `htmlspecialchars` for non-numeric field data when injecting them into your html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ob_start()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [`ob_get_clean()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) to buffer all output into a variable, then output that variable, like this:

```
ob_start();
print "Hello"; // Prints to buffer instead of screen
$out = ob_get_clean(); // Contains: Hello
echo $out; // Prints: Hello
```